# How can I reset the dropzone in this code?

Tags: reset, dropzone.js, custom-code

```js
Dropzone.options.imageFile = {
    url: HOST_NAME + USER_NAME + BUILDER_API +'image/',
    method: 'POST',
    // enter code here
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png',
    paramName: "imagefile", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 10, // MB
    //addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 2,
    init: function() {
        this.on("success", function(file, response) {
            image_id = response.id;
            IMAGES.push(image_id);
            check_files();
        }),
        this.on("removedfile", function(file, response){
            data = JSON.parse(file.xhr.response);
            alert(data['id']);
        });
    },
};
```

What I have to do to reset the dropzone completely?

Comment: Did you got your answere.
I'm facing same problem

Comment: I have the same problem - rmoveAllFiles is mentioned over and over again - how to you execute that on the item above... Dropzone.options.imageFile.removeAllFiles() does not work

Comment: Got it - see my answer below

Answer (score 13):

Not 100% sure I understood the question, but I presume you want to be able to reuse the dropzone instance from its original state.

Technically you want to call `removeAllFiles()` and that will remove all the files.

Here is an example that shows you how to add a remove all files with one button: [Remove all files with one button](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Remove-all-files-with-one-button)

Also, there were other people trying to do the same thing that you are looking for: [Reset dropzone to Pristine state](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/44)

Answer (score 8):

This is the answer to that question and many like it on stackoverflow... to removeAllFiles on a NON-programmatically created dropzone (http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration), you'd execute (using the OP's ID):

```
 var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("#imageFile");
 myDropzone.removeAllFiles();
```

The problem is that this does NOT put the nice "upload an image here" message back for me - just leaves an inexplicable white box - one more step to fix that.

```
 $(".dz-message").removeClass("hidden");
```

That will show the original message.

Answer (score 0):

I create a button and put this code. when clicking on the button, it's hidden and your dropzone is seen like a page refresh.

```js
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $('#btn').hide();
    $('.dropzone')[0].dropzone.files.forEach(function(file) {
        file.previewTemplate.remove();
    });

    $('.dropzone').removeClass('dz-started');
});
```

Comment: Simply providing code without any explanation is not very helpful. Can you give some more text, please? Also I cannot see what is the additional value regarding other answers here.