# Reinitialize/Reset dropzone after form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

I'm using the [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) to upload image on ruby on rails .Here is my HTML code

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" id="drop-zone-container">
    <%= form_tag '/settlement_proofs', method: :post, class: 'dropzone form', id: 'media-dropzone' do %>
        <div class="fallback">
          <%= file_field_tag 'attachment', multiple: true%>
        </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I initialized dropzone as

```
$("#media-dropzone").dropzone({
    acceptedFiles: pg.constants.ACCEPTED_FORMAT,
    maxFilesize: pg.constants.ATTACHMENT_MAX_FILE_SIZE, //In MB
    maxFiles: pg.constants.ATTACHMENT_MAX_SIZE,
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    removedfile: function (file) {
        if (file.xhr.responseText.length > 0) {
            var fileId = JSON.parse(file.xhr.responseText).id;
            $.ajax({
                url: pg.constants.url.SETTLEMENT_BASE_URL + fileId,
                method: 'DELETE',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#uploaded_attachment').val($("#uploaded_attachment").val().replace(result.id + ',', ""));
                    $('#settlement_proof_status span').fadeOut(0);
                    var _ref;
                    return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;

                },
                error: function () {
                    $('#settlement_proof_status').text(I18n.t('attachment_deletion_error')).fadeIn();
                }

            });
        }

    },
    init: function () {

        this.on("success", function (file, message) {
            debugger;
            appendContent(message.attachment.url, message.id);
        });

        this.on("error", function (file, message) {
            $('#settlement_proof_status span').text(message).fadeIn();
            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
        });
        $('#settlement_invoice_submit_btn').click(function () {
            $("#new_settlement_invoice").submit();
        });
        $('#uploaded_attachment').change(function () {
            if (this.value.length == 0) {
                this.removeAllFiles();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

After I submit the form through AJAX, I need the dropzone field to reset with the default image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21702526/how-can-i-reset-dropzone-by-this-code

Comment: In your provided link, user is using div instead of form to post the data.Here In my case I'm using form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue myself.
At first I remove the form from its parents element.It removed the existing dropzone instance.Then I create the form using the jQuery and reinitialize the dropzone again.
Here is my complete code

```
 // To reset dropzone before popup load
    var resetDropzone = function () {

        $('#drop-zone-container').empty();

        var $form = makeElement('form', {
            action: window.pg.constants.url.SETTLEMENT_BASE_URL,
            method: 'post',
            id: 'settlement-proof-form',
            class: 'dropzone'
        });

        $('#drop-zone-container').append($form);

        var settlmentProofDropZone;
        $("#settlement-proof-form").dropzone({
            acceptedFiles: pg.constants.ACCEPTED_FORMAT,
            maxFilesize: pg.constants.ATTACHMENT_MAX_FILE_SIZE, //In MB
            maxFiles: pg.constants.ATTACHMENT_MAX_SIZE,
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            removedfile: function (file) {
                if (file.xhr.responseText.length > 0) {
                    var fileId = JSON.parse(file.xhr.responseText).id;
                    $.ajax({
                        url: pg.constants.url.SETTLEMENT_BASE_URL + fileId,
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            $('#uploaded_attachment').val($("#uploaded_attachment").val().replace(result.id + ',', ""));
                            $('#settlement_proof_status span').fadeOut(0);
                            var _ref;
                            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;

                        },
                        error: function () {
                            $('#settlement_proof_status').text(I18n.t('attachment_deletion_error')).fadeIn();
                        }

                    });
                }

            },
            init: function () {
                settlmentProofDropZone = this;

                this.on("success", function (file, message) {
                    appendContent(message.attachment.url, message.id);
                });
            }
        });

    };

    function makeElement(element, options) {
        var $formField = document.createElement(element);
        $.each(options, function (key, value) {
            if (key === 'innerHTML') {
                $formField.innerHTML = value;
            }
            else {
                $formField.setAttribute(key, value);
            }
        });
        return $formField;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 30):

```
this.on("complete", function(file) { 
   this.removeAllFiles(true); 
})
```

write the above code in `INIT` function.

this removes all files in dropzone and RESETS the dropzone  to initial state.

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-reset

Comment: I already tried it out.But I don't know why removeAllFiles(true) removes the file from server as well

Answer (score 8):

I took an example from both Senug Nam Kim and J Santosh:

```
// Where .reset-dz is the class of a button
$('.reset-dz').on('click', function(e){
    var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("#user-post-submit");
    myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true); 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
//DropZone Initiation Section
init: function() {
    this.on('success', function(file, json) {
    });

    this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
    });

    this.on('drop', function(file) {
    });

    this.on('removedfile', function(file) {
    });

    this.on('complete', function(file) {
    });

    this.on('error', function(file) {
    });

    this.on('resetFiles', function() {
        if(this.files.length != 0){
            for(i=0; i<this.files.length; i++){
                this.files[i].previewElement.remove();
            }
            this.files.length = 0;
        }
    });
}

function JS_ClearDropZone() {
    //DropZone Object Get
    var objDZ = Dropzone.forElement("div#objDropzone");
    //"resetFiles" Event Call
    objDZ.emit("resetFiles");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Every answer here is incredibly complicated. I have a dropzone in a modal with some ajax to draw the uploaded/complete file on the page. If the user adds ANOTHER image to the gallery, I wanted to reset the dropzone in that modal without refreshing the page. The answer? See my solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45247184/179571

Answer (score 2):

Every Solution here is not for React, Any one can explain how it can we done with React
Here is the code to remove files after upload in react

```
...
...


const initCallback = (dropzone) => {
    myDropzone = dropzone
  }

const eventHandlers = {
  init: initCallback,
  queuecomplete: () => {
    if (myDropzone && clearDropzone) {
      myDropzone.removeAllFiles()
    }
  }
}

....
...
```

Comment: It works on Web as well.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution built on script. For version 5.4.0

1. Add it in you script what connect dropzone.js

> `$('button#submit_button').click(function () {
>         $('.dz-preview').empty();
>         $('.dz-message').show();
>       });`

2. And in dropzone.js add line >>> $('.dz-message').hide();

   before return _this3.updateTotalUploadProgress(); (line 1277)

> `this.on("uploadprogress", function () {
>           $('.dz-message').hide();
>           return _this3.updateTotalUploadProgress();
>         });`